# « Vous essayez de me faire avoir » : quelle est l'expression correcte ?

Tags: traduction, expressions

Dans le [French phrasebook de Wikivoyage](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/French_phrasebook), pour « You're cheating me » (dans le contexte du shopping, le vendeur essaie de vendre pour un prix trop élevé) la phrase recommendée en français est:

> Vous essayez de me faire avoir.

Ça me semble incorrect, aurais-je oublié le français ? J'aurais plutôt dit « Vous essayez de m'avoir ».

Laquelle de ces phrases est correcte ?

*(Bonus si vous avez une expression plus courante, et facile à prononcer/comprendre.)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En français on dirait : *vous essayez de m'avoir*, ou encore *vous essayez de me rouler* / *de m'arnaquer*

Dans cette situation on pourrait également utiliser une phrase plus tranchante :

*N'essayez pas de m'arnaquer !*